# SQL выборка с условием по полю Key

Tags: mysql

Задача в следующем: нужно выбрать не индексированные поля таблицы, например так:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM table
WHERE key <> 'PRI'
```

Но mysql ругается на `key`. Я так понимаю это зарезервированное слово и использовать его в таком виде как у меня нельзя. Как можно обойти эту ситуацию?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А если так:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM `table`
WHERE `key` <> 'PRI'
```

Comment: Пасиба! Так заработало :)